# c# Visa 3d Secure Implementation

Tags: c#, credit-card, 3d-secure

can someone give a sample implementation of 3d secure for an ecommerce application?

Comment: The implementation is going to depend wholey on the payment gateway you are using to authorise the credit-card transactions.  Which service are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation depends on payment gateway providers. you will have to contact their support or check their manual for it.

I have worked with "The Logic Group" and BT payment gateway providers in UK so if you are using one of these then let me know I can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give a lot of information in your question. Your options depend on what you're attempting to acheive.

Your options are either

- You're integrating with a payment service provider. Most will offer 3d secure processing, ask them for help.
- You're rolling your own 3d secure service. In this case you will need to either purchase or develop an MPI (Merchant Plug-In) that passes the 3dsecure messages to Visa and MasterCard. In this case your best option is to purchase an MPI from a 3rd party vendor, otherwise be prepared for a lengthy and costly integration directly with Visa and MasterCard.